# Why do I get a StackoverflowError on when Groovy JsonBuilder tries to serialize an Expando?

Tags: groovy, expando, jsonbuilder

I am getting a StackoverflowError (not traced back to my code) when I try to serialize an Expando.  Reproduced with groovy shell:

```
... groovy-2.0.6/bin/groovysh new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(new Expando(name:'hello')).toString()
FATAL: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:77)
        at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(InvocationTargetException.java:54)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
...
```

This should work right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow..It's a bug.  Looks like it was introduced at 1.8.8

works at 1.8.6:

```
groovy-1.8.6/bin/groovysh new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(new Expando(name:'hello')).toString();

===> {"name":"hello"}
```

StackoverflowError at 1.8.8:

```
groovy-1.8.8/bin/groovysh new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(new Expando(name:'hello')).toString();
FATAL: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Looks like there is a bug filed on 2.1.0rc1: [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5918](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5918)

Comment: Good catch, [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/pull/120) that hopefully fixes it

Comment: The pull request has been accepted so the next version of 2.1.0 (either final or rc3 if there is one) should work

Comment: Looks like it's fixed in 2.0.7, 2.1.0 and 2.1.0-rc-3 :-)